# Is the physical ordering of rows maintained when adding new rows to a table with a clustered index?

Tags: sql, database, informix

In IDS?..SE?.. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and others automatically insert new rows into the appropiate location in the datafile to maintain the clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Informix handles clustered indexes is by rebuilding the table (and index) so that the data in the table is in the correct physical sequence for the index at the time when the index is created.  Thereafter, rows are inserted wherever seems most appropriate, which does not continue to preserve the clustered order.  This has been the case since (<s>Informix-SQL 1.10 in 1985</s>) Informix-SQL 2.10 from 1986 (possibly 2.00; I don't have a manual for that still) through Informix Dynamic Server 11.70 in 2010.

The statement:

```
ALTER INDEX idxname TO NOT CLUSTERED;
```

is always very quick.  The complementary statement:

```
ALTER INDEX idxname TO CLUSTERED;
```

is often a slow process, involving creating a full new version of the table and the index before dropping the old table and index.

---

*The ISQL 1.10 manual does not have ALTER INDEX; the 2.10 manual does has ALTER INDEX.*

Comment: "...inserted wherever seems most appropiate..." meaning like at EOF?.. I no longer use 2.10, I'm up to 4.10 (DOS) and working fine under Virtual PC 2007. UNLOADING the table with an ORDER BY in my SELECT STATEMENT and recreating the table and indexes would be the equivalent of creating a clustered index?.. I do this every seven days and works well with 20,000 nrows, but can imagine would take a long time with 500,000 nrows.

Comment: My objective is when I query one of my 20,000 customers, I want quick response in locating all of the queried customers transactions, which are in a child table.. If the customers transactions are scattered throughout the table then it takes longer to return them, whereas clustering these transactions by customer.id keeps them together.

Comment: @Frank: 'meaning like at EOF'; if you've not deleted anything, then yes at the end.  If you've deleted rows, then those slots may be reused.  Yes, UNLOAD with ORDER BY and then LOAD would be essentially the same as creating a clustered index - though the workload on the system is higher because the clustered index doesn't have to transfer all the data to the client on unload and back to the server on load.

Comment: Periodically clustering the index on customer ID will keep things close enough together that the response time won't suffer noticeably.  Sure, a few records might be scattered away from the rest, but you are pretty unlikely to notice, and the majority will be close together.

Comment: no rows in this table are deleted by users or a proc, so new rows are placed at EOF. I experimented unloading, reloading and creating non-clustered index on fk_id vs. alter index to clustered and query retrieval time was much faster with non-clustered index!.. I thought retrieval would be quicker with clustered index vs. non-clustered. Could you explain how the cost-based query optimizer handles this?

Comment: @Frank: it would be easy to explain "no difference" (it is what I'd expect). It is harder to explain "much faster". There may be something I'm not aware of related to the DOS environment. Did you run an UPDATE STATISTICS operation for one and not the other by any chance? I wonder if it is because you somehow ended up with files that are physically contiguous on disk with the explicit (rather than just logically contiguous on disk)? Or if there is some other way that the files ended up extra advantageously placed? You say "much faster"; what measurements did you make to back that up?

Comment: whenever i run the reorg proc for this table, i update statistics for all tables, then a dos batch script defrags the 256MB partition. the only thing i've changed in the proc is creating an index on fk_id with and without clustering. set explain on, creates sqlexplan.out, where estimated cost for retrieving 120 fk_id rows is 3 with clustering vs. cost without clustering was 1.  Also, would it be more advantage if disk sector size is 32K (2GB partition) or 4K (256MB partition)?

Comment: @Frank: IIRC, the cost-based optimizer was introduced into OnLine and SE 5.00, and the 4.1x version is still rule-based.  I suggest you go with whatever works best.  Since it seems that non-clustered is better than cluster (though I would not hang much reliance on a difference between 1 and 3 in cost from SET EXPLAIN; what was the measured difference in response time?), then go with the non-clustered information.  You might also look at what `bcheck` says about the differences between the clustered and non-clustered C-ISAM files.

Comment: retrieval time is about 50% faster without cluster index.. what I cant understand is if clustering directly accesses the root node, why would it be slower than non-clustered?.. also, since SE's page size is 512 bytes, is it better to have 32K disk sectors vs. 4K, or would 512 byte disk sectors be optimal?

Comment: @Jonathan: Oh, and the 4.10 (DOS) release notes said the following:..."It is particularly important to run the UPDATE STATISTICS command occasionally. You should use it frequently when there is a great deal of data manipulation occurring.  This command updates the statistics used by the query optimizer. The query optimizer determines the most effective method for retrieving data from the database.  Because the optimizer is cost-based, the statistics it uses (number of rows, minimum or maximum value in an index column, and so on) should be as up-to-date as possible."

Comment: @Frank: OK - if you've got the SE 4.10 release notes and they say it is a 'cost-based optimizer', then my memory of what happened between 1988 and 1991 is fading...not a big surprise to me.  SE's index page size is usually 1024 these days, but there were certainly 512-byte editions.  I'd probably stick with 4 KB pages, unless you can measure a performance improvement with another size.  Frankly, I've no idea whether going to 32 KB or 0.5 KB would be better; there are just too many variable factors to deal with.  I don't have any explanation.

Comment: ok, the solution is to experiment, like I did with cluster vs. no cluster. I'll preliminarily assume that using 32K disk blocks vs. 4K or 512B will be better since having 32K blocks in disk cache would be a faster read-ahead. As it is, I rarely see the disk access LED light up, meaning my app runs most of the time in memory. My app is probably one of a handful of INFORMIX-SQL (DOS) running in a virtual hard disk, but it runs exceptionally fast!.. but I'm always looking for ways to make it even faster!

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for IDS but I can for some you mentioned.

It depends on the platforms: does it use pages and does it separate data from index tree?

Generally,  physical ordering of rows *is not* maintained: only logical ordering can be

Reason: you can't "make room" on a fixed size page (as Bohemian suggested)

So if you extend a row (eg add more data to a long varchar) or insert in between (`ID=3` between rows `id IN (2,4)`) then the one of the following happens

- row is taken out to a new page with pointers
- row overflows (SQL Server 2005+ for example)
- page is split

This results in logical/index fragmentation and reduced data density (per page): which is why we have index maintenance to remove this.